# How do I install pybonjour on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, pybonjour

Getting this error `ImportError: No module named pybonjour`

How do I install pybonjour on Ubuntu 14.04.

Tried `sudo apt-get install pybonjour` and `pip install pybonjour`, no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Install libavahi-compat-libdnssd1

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libavahi-compat-libdnssd1
   ```
2. Download [pybonjour](https://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/downloads/detail?name=pybonjour-1.1.1.tar.gz&can=2&q=) and unpack it with

   ```
   tar zxf pybonjour-1.1.1.tar.gz
   ```
3. Installation

   ```
   cd pybonjour-1.1.1
   sudo python setup.py install
   ```
4. Use

   ```
   import pybonjour
   ```

Also see https://code.google.com/p/pybonjour/ for why you need to install libavahi-compat-libdnssd1

Comment: Have you tried instaling bonjour on windows? Is there any other method than installing iTunes?

Comment: Not sure about iTunes,  but on Windows you must install bonjour which you can get here https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/index.html

Comment: you mean I need to install in the SDK?

Comment: Yes,  that's what the installation instructions say on the pybonjour Google code page